# Problem with class constructor inside the class library

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a class library with the class I shown. but I'm getting errors.
I thought that the constructor is called when I'm creating the object, why it already requires arguments?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework 4.8

If I add a comment on 15 line, the two first errors disappear

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace CSVDataViewer
{ 
    class CSV
    {
        public List<string> FirstColumn { get; set; }
        public List<string> SecondColumn { get; set; }
        // Line 15​
        public CSV(string path, char separator) 
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                List<string> listA = new List<string>();
                List<string> listB = new List<string>();
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(separator);
​
                    listA.Add(values[0]);
                    listB.Add(values[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- `CS1056 Unexpected character ''` at line 15
- `CS1519 Invalid token '' in class, struct or interface member declaration` at line 15
- `CS1056 Unexpected character ''` at line 26

Comment: Code looks fine to me.

Comment: What is the file encoding?

Comment: Both lines contain an unprintable Unicode character `\u200b`.  Highlight both lines and press Enter to replace them with a truly blank line.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors when I try your code.

Comment: Is it this file you are getting error or in some other file?

Comment: @BACON is right, there is a [Zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) on both lines 15 & 26

Comment: Thanks guys! It works